Is there an English equivalent of Arabic "gowatra" - performing a task with none of the necessary training?
In Iraqi Arabic, there's a term "gowatra". In a sentence, the expression will be used like, "it is not guatra [to do this or that, to have this, to get this]". That word or idiom simply means you can't just get a job somewhere, or pretty much do anything that requires skills without any prior knowledge, certificates, experience, etc. An example:

Monica: I wonder if my best friend, who is a teacher, can let me work with her as her assistant.
Miranda: People can't just get into positions that require a set of skills. It is not [insert word] to do such things.

To note, the expression doesn't have to pertain to working or jobs. Just any thing that relates to jumping into an adept position without any skills or knowledge. So they say, "it is not guwatra to do that".
I don't know the Arabic word's exact etymological meaning. But that's how it's used in sentences (as you saw above). Can't think of an equivalent English term. Both single words and idioms are welcome.

Idiomatically: “That’s just not how it’s done.”

"It's not something you can do just like that"?

How does it differ from "easy", "simple", and other everyday words like that?

It's not clear what meaning you're looking for.  Is this indicating specifically that something is not possible without relevant qualifications?  Not possible for just anyone?  Not appropriate?  Not acceptable?  Not in accordance with prevailing custom?  Not easy to do?  Likely to incur people's anger or disdain?

It may not be cricket, but English does use the borrow word kosher to mean proper, the original meaning of the Hebrew word.

One does not simply walk into Mordor...

It's not kosher?

More usage examples would be great! I usually need a wide variety of examples to understand what an idiom means.

A bland expression here might be "entry-level".

I don’t think it’s possible to express the notion of doing something without qualifications/preparation (or winging it, another useful expression) using a structure like the one in your examples. To say that teaching is not something you can just wing, you would say, “It is not gowatra to teach”, is that right? So gowatra would be an adjective describing the not-wingable activity? All the English terms that express the notion of (not) winging something are based around the verb for carrying out the activity, so by necessity you’ll end up with a completely different construction.

@gidds More so "not possible without relevant qualifications", including skills.

@JanusBahsJacquet "Winging it" sounds close enough. Make it an official answer below. :)

If anyone is interested, the current expression for that in French is "y aller au talent". I am writing "current" because this is an expression used by 16 to 20 years olds, and it may change with time. It is very good, though.


performing a task with none of the necessary training

The closest term/idiom I know of is to "wing it".
From Webster (online):

to do or try to do something without much practice or preparation
"I hadn't practiced the part, so I got up there and winged it."

So in your case the answer would change to:

Miranda: People can't just get into positions that require a set of skills. You can't just wing it.


As an aside, if we're talking about teaching, you very much can do that here in Oklahoma.

Yep, this one I think will be a 'best answer' for me.

There is the somewhat tautologous but idiomatic expression

One can't just casually walk into such a post.

The senses below are selected for relevance.

casually: in a way that shows indifference, apathy, or a lack of intention or understanding:

She strolled in casually, as if she weren’t late. [Dictionary.com]



casually: without much care or thought; without paying attention to detail [Oxford Learner's
Dictionary]


casually: [done] done without much thought, effort, or concern [Britannica Dictionary]

And I see @Andy Bonner has overlapped:

walk into: achieve a state or position easily or undeservedly.

No one has the right to walk straight into a well-paid job for life. Oxford Dictionary of English; courtesy of
Google]



The recent memes based on "one does not simply walk into..." may be the closest some non-native speakers have seen to this.  Depending on context that may be a good thing, or it might be worth avoiding setting up that image

A little underwhelming but I think 'just choose' or 'just decide' seem to fit:

You don't just decide to become an astronaut.  NASA is selective.
You can't just choose to become a financial advisor. You need to go to school and be certified.
You can't just decide to become a teacher. You need a have master's degree in this state.


The closest is probably "flying by the seat of your pants".

Longman gives fly by the seat of your pants: informal - to have to
deal with a situation by guessing what to do, because you know very
little about it.

You also have the more modern "fake it until you make it."
Both can be used in the negative - saying you can't do that.

"We knew that we didn't want to work with insurance at all," Meehan says, "so our business plan centered on being cash-based. For that model to work, though, you need a system in place. You can't just fly by the seat of your pants."  https://www.apta.org/apta-magazine/2017/04/01/mastering-cash-based-practice

..................

Compared to other fast-growing jobs in tech, data engineers top the list coming in over back end developers, senior data scientists, CRM developers, and many more.
Why else is there such a high demand for data engineers? Companies are
investing in large-scale data projects that the industry just can’t
keep up with, not to mention their very specialized training, where
you can’t just fake it until you make it!
https://www.crystalequation.com/post/4-of-it-s-most-in-demand-professionals


Wearing the Crown is no sinecure.
A sinecure is a position requiring little or no work but giving the holder status or financial benefit.
Examples in Cambridge disctionnary
If you have a cushy job — one that pays, but involves minimal work — then you have a sinecure. "Because he was the brother of the CEO, he was offered a sinecure in the company: he showed up each day and collected a paycheck, but others actually did his work."
Examples in Vocabulary.com
However, It doesn't mean that you have no skills in the domain,  just that there is very few work to perform.

One can dabble in a field. One shouldn't dabble when training is required.
Sorry, dabblers aren't welcome here.
Dabbling isn't permitted for serious work.
This is, of course, an application beyond a single task.

I think dabbling is more about being part-time / weekend / hobby (time committment).  It doesn't really imply anything about the amount of expertise or skill being wielded.

One could certainly use trivial, which means easy, simple, straightforward.
